# Django can't import module due to a circular import

Tags: python, django

Following a tutorial and am have the module

views.py file

```
#attempt2/src/products/views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ProductForm, RawProductForm
from .models import Product

def product_create_view(request):
    #this creates an instance of that form
    my_form = RawProductForm()
    context = {
        "form": my_form
    }
    return render(request, "product/product_create.html", context)
```

But I get the following error

```
 File "C:\Users\dancc\dev2\attempt2\src\products\views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .forms import ProductForm, RawProductForm
  File "C:\Users\dancc\dev2\attempt2\src\products\forms.py", line 4, in <module>
    from products.views import product_create_view
ImportError: cannot import name 'product_create_view' from partially initialized module 'products.views' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\dancc\dev2\attempt2\src\products\views.py)
```

I've tried searching to see where it might be importing a different product_create_view but there is not another one, none of the files or folders' names repeat

this is forms.py

```
#attempt2/src/products/forms.py
from django import forms

from products.views import product_create_view
from .models import Product

class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'title',
            'description',
            'price'
        ]

        
#This is what product_create_view is using
class RawProductForm(forms.Form):
    title       = forms.CharField()
    description = forms.CharField()
    price       = forms.DecimalField()
```

This is models.py file

```
#attempt2/src/products/models.py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Product(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=120) #max_length required
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price       = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10000)
    summary     = models.TextField()
```

This is views.py file

```
#attempt2/src/products/views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ProductForm, RawProductForm
from .models import Product

...

def product_create_view(request):
    #this creates an instance of that form
    my_form = RawProductForm()
    context = {
        'form': my_form
    }
    return render(request, "product/product_create.html", context)
```

Here are the folders
[image]

Comment: remove the `from products.views import product_create_view` line in your `forms.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing the `product_create_view` from the `products.views` module, but in your `forms.py`, you do not use that function. Since the `products.forms` module imports the `products.views` module, and vice versa, this creates a cycle when importing one of the two.

You can remove the `from products.views import product_create_view` line from the `forms.py` file, and thus simply let the view use the forms you defined, not in the opposite direction.